# Why does my JTable throw intermittent exceptions?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable

I am working on a Swing program that uses a `JTable` to display information to the user. The table currently has over 700 entries but I have found a very weird bug that seems to be reproducible randomly. Sometimes the `JTable` will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` with Index: 0, Size: 0. I have compiled and ran my program multiple times without changing ANYTHING and this exception would come up randomly, when the exception does not come up, the program behaves normally.

I am unable to provide code for this problem because it requires over 10 files in order to run. Why might this be happening with `JTable`? I find it really weird how a program can throw an exception during one run of the program and not throw an exception at another run of the same program with no code changes... Are there any commonly known errors that cause this kind of behavior in programs?

I am not really sure which parts of the code I should include but here is some additional information.

I have created a Custom `TableModel` called `PlayerTableModel` which is used to render the `JTable`, The data is stored in `ArrayLists` that are in another class. Here is the code for the `TableModel`

```
public class PlayerTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    ArrayList<User> users = FileHandler.getAllPlayers();
    ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player> summaries = FileHandler.getAllSummaries();

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {

        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {

        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        User user = users.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            if (user.getSteamId().equalsIgnoreCase(summaries.get(rowIndex).getSteamID())) {  // This is line 39
                return summaries.get(rowIndex).getPersonaName();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        case 1:
            return user.getDateAdded();
        case 2:
            return user.getDateUpdated();
        case 3:
            return user.getNumberOfBans();
        case 4:
            return user.getNumberOfGameBans();
        case 5:
            return user.getDaysSinceLastBan();
        case 6:
            return user.getSteamId();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {

        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return "ID";
        case 1:
            return "Date added";
        case 2:
            return "Date updated";
        case 3:
            return "VAC bans";
        case 4:
            return "Game bans";
        case 5:
            return "Last ban (days)";
        case 6:
            return "64-Bit SteamID";
        }
        return null;

    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

When running the program, sometimes I get this exception which seems to be some sort of thread issue?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   PlayerTableModel.getValueAt(PlayerTableModel.java:39)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

The data is written and read from file, using the `FileHandler` class:

```
public class FileHandler implements Serializable {

    private static ArrayList<User> tracked = new ArrayList<User>();

    private static ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player> trackedSummaries = new ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>();

    private static ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player> trackedSummariesUnsorted = new ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>();

    private static ArrayList<String[]> games = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private static String savedString = "";

    private static String APIKEY = "";

    public static void writeToFile(String fileName, Object objToWrite) {

        try {
            // Write object to file.
            FileOutputStream fOS = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(fOS);
            oOS.writeObject(objToWrite);
            oOS.close();

            // Write string to text file so that it can be displayed.
            if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("apikey.txt")) {
                File file = new File(fileName);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
                pw.print(objToWrite);
                pw.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readFromFile(String fileName, String objType) {
        FileInputStream fIS;
        try {

            fIS = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);

            if (objType.equalsIgnoreCase("ArrayList<User>")) {
                tracked = (ArrayList<User>) oIS.readObject();
            } else if (objType.equalsIgnoreCase("ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>")) {
                if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("summaries.tmp")) {
                    trackedSummaries = (ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>) oIS.readObject();
                }
                if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("s_unsorted.tmp")) {
                    trackedSummariesUnsorted = (ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>) oIS.readObject();
                }
            } else if (objType.equalsIgnoreCase("ArrayList<String[]>")) {
                games = (ArrayList<String[]>) oIS.readObject();
            } else if (objType.equalsIgnoreCase("apikey")) {
                APIKEY = (String) oIS.readObject();
            }else {
                System.out.println("Object type " + objType + " needs to be implemented!");
            }

            oIS.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<User> getAllPlayers() {
        return tracked;
    }

    public static ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player> getAllSummaries() {
        return trackedSummaries;
    }

    public static ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player> getAllSummariesUnsorted() {
        return trackedSummariesUnsorted;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String[]> getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public static String getAPIKey() {

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("apikey.txt"));
            APIKEY = br.readLine();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BanTracker.getFrames()[0], "File not found! Did you save your API key?");
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return APIKEY;
    }

    public static void updateArrayList(ArrayList<User> a) {
        tracked = a;
    }

}
```

Comment: In my experience, this occurs because you're mutating the `TableModel` from a thread other then the EDT.  I've seen this in particular when using a `TableRowSorter` of some kind

Comment: *"I find it really weird how a program can throw an exception during one run of the program and not throw an exception at another run of the same program with no code changes"* - Can you say "Hello race condition"

Comment: Without a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, it's all guess work, This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have not worked with threads before, I haven't started any new threads in my program. Also I am not sure how I would reproduce this problem using highlights of my code because I am not sure which part is causing it.

Comment: As I said, without some idea of how the error is produced or how your code works, it's all just guess work.  We use `JTable` ALOT (some times with 1, 000's of rows) and don't have any problems until people start messing with the model/table from outside the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have included additional information along with the exception I am getting. If more information is required, I'll add it.

Comment: Under what use-cases does the error occur?  What were you doing when it happened?

Comment: Can you just include `FileHandler` also?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The error sometimes occurs when I compile the program and go the the `JTabbedPane` that contains the `JTable`. The `JTable` is first initialized when the program runs.

Comment: Make sure your code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: @durron597 I have added the code for `FileHandler` in my post. @camickr Would I have to explicitly declare this or is it done automatically? I haven't worked with threads before.

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel Does the exception happen at startup or does it happen in the middle of execution?

Comment: @durron597 My program has multiple panes and one of them contain the `JTable` in question. The error sometimes occurs after clicking on the `JTabbedPane` containing the `JTable`.

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel Ah, `static`, `static` everywhere, how this will bite you when you're unawares...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FileHandler class is not loading the files on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), so you're causing a race condition between that thread and the Event Dispatch Thread.

You should not be accessing your files statically anyway; inject the Users and the Summaries into the table model at creation, before the JTable is even rendered. In other words, just create a constructor:

```
public class PlayerTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private final List<User> users;
  private final List<PlayerSummary.Player> summaries;

  public PlayerTableModel(List<User> users, List<PlayerSummary.Player> summaries) {
    this.users = new ArrayList<User>(users);
    this.summaries = new ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>(summaries);
  }
}
```

Then, before even constructing the JTable, ensure that the files are loaded:

```
TableModel model = new PlayerTableModel(FileHandler.getAllPlayers(),
             FileHandler.getAllSummaries());
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

This should ensure that all the loading happens when it's supposed to (when the program starts), and the error should disappear.

Also, try modifying your TableModel to do this:

```
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return Math.min(users.size(), summaries.size());
}
```

I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but I think you will be much, much happier if you do this:

```
public class CompletePlayer {
  public final User user;
  public final PlayerSummer.Player summary;
}
```

Then, only use one ArrayList instead of two. Read Ernest Friedman's post [here about parallel arrays](http://www.coderanch.com/t/383868/java/java/Sorting-set-arrays)

Comment: Line 39 would be `if (user.getSteamId().equalsIgnoreCase(summaries.get(rowIndex).getSteamID())) {`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by refactor everything in `getValueAt` to use local variables. I am currently using the variable `user` that is defined locally.

Comment: I am still getting the same exception although it occurs a lot less frequently.

Comment: I have added the changes you suggested to `getRowCount()`. Now instead of an exception being thrown the table is just empty (I think this is  because the size of user is still 0).

Comment: I think you should change all the parts of your code to use the unified object concept of `CompletePlayer` (and add any other relevant data classes) rather than parallel `ArrayLists`, and I think your problem will go away.

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel Also, it's `summaries` that's size 0, not `users`, as far as I can tell. I don't think the problem is in code you've shown me, but using the combined class will probably fix your problem in the process.

Comment: I have tested it using just `users` and it works fine as far as I can tell. I will try to refactor my code to use the unified object `CompletePlayer` to see if it works out.

Comment: I was able to refactor my code to use `CompletePlayer` but now I am experiencing another problem. I have a button that usually refreshes the `JTable` using `model.fireTableDataChanged();` but now since the data is injected before the table is created it no longer refreshes. I have also tried `repaint()` without any luck. The only way the `JTable` wil update is if I exit and reopen the program. Is there a way to update the `JTable` using a button?

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel You should ask a new question.