# Updating JTable on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am working with a `JTable` with a Custom Table Model found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508132/why-does-my-jtable-throw-intermittent-exceptions/31508447?noredirect=1#comment51015703_31508447). I have updated my code with the suggestions provided in that post and have run into a new problem. The change I have made to my code was to inject an `ArrayList<CompletedPlayer>` into my `JTable` to avoid issues with threads. After doing that, the code to update my table by pressing a button has stopped working.

The code used to initialize the `JTable` is the following:

```
TableModel model = new PlayerTableModel(FileHandler.getCompletedPlayers());
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

The code I used to update the `JTable` is the following:

```
JButton btnRefreshAllPlayers = new JButton("Refresh");

btnRefreshAllPlayers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        PlayerTableModel model = (PlayerTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.fireTableDataChanged();

    }

});
```

I have also tried using `repaint()` but this does not work either. As of right now, the only way to get the `JTable` to update is to close and reopen the program. `FileHandler` has the `ArrayList` I am using for the `JTable` which increases in size as the user adds more players.

Why doesn't `fireTableDataChanged()` detect any changes?

Comment: 1- You should never be calling `fireTableXxx` methods outside of the context of the model, that's not your responsibility. 2- From the looks of your code, there is nothing been updated in your `Refresh` action...

Comment: Maybe, you should reload the data, create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the `JTable` instead

Comment: I have searched on stackoverflow and a couple of people have said to use  that method. I have also tried setting a new model with the updated `ArrayList` and it worked but did not keep the table row widths I previously set. Is there a proper way to update the `JTable`?

Comment: No, you should not call any `fireTableXxx` methods outside of the context of the `TableModel` itself, people suggesting otherwise are simply wrong and it will cause you issues in the future.  From the looks of your code, nothing has changed.  If you've updated the `TableModel` according to the answer provided in your previous question, then there is no relationship with the data in the model to the external source.  You need to manually reload the data from the external source, create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the table

Comment: Isn't the relationship with the external source established in this line `TableModel model = new PlayerTableModel(FileHandler.getCompletedPlayers());`?

Comment: How?  At worst, that's simply going to reference the `ArrayList` in the `FileHandler`, so if that's never updated, how will anything else update, at best, based on the advice of previous question, it's a copy of the `ArrayList` at the time that the `TableModel` was created, so even if you did reload the data from the `FileHandler`, there is no connection between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have searched on stackoverflow and a couple of people have said to use that method.

No, you should not call any `fireTableXxx` methods outside of the context of the `TableModel` itself, people suggesting otherwise are simply wrong and it will cause you issues in the future.  From the looks of your code, nothing has changed.  If you've updated the `TableModel` according to the answer provided in your previous question, then there is no relationship with the data in the model to the external source.  You need to manually reload the data from the external source, create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the table

For example...

```
JButton btnRefreshAllPlayers = new JButton("Refresh");

btnRefreshAllPlayers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        TableModel model = new PlayerTableModel(FileHandler.getCompletedPlayers());
        table.setModel(model);

    }

});
```

> I have also tried setting a new model with the updated ArrayList and it worked but did not keep the table row widths I previously set.

This is a reasonable thing for the table to do, because it has no idea if the new model has the same properties/columns as the old, so it resets them.

You could walk the `ColumnModel`, storing the column widths in a `List` or `Map` before you apply the model and reapply the widths

> Is there a proper way to update the JTable?

You could provide your `TableModel` with a refresh method, which could load the data itself and trigger a `tableDataChanged` event

```
public class PlayerTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final List<PlayerSummary.Player> summaries;

    public PlayerTableModel(List<PlayerSummary.Player> summaries) {
        this.summaries = new ArrayList<PlayerSummary.Player>(summaries);
    }
    // Other TabelModel methods...

    public void refresh() {
        summaries = new ArrayList<>(FileHandler.getCompletedPlayers());
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Then you would need to call this method in your `ActionListener`...

```
PlayerTableModel model = (PlayerTableModel)table.getMode();
model.refresh();
```

Comment: I have implemented the `refresh` method as you suggested and it's working. Thank you!